# How deploy a encrypted Data Bag as a file in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I've a encrypted data bag which is common for all environments(including prod and all test environments). I don't want to store that file in **SCM** as chef recipes. I would like to use the data bag in a recipe to create a file when ever chef runs.

Something like this:

```
        knife data bag show --secret-file <secret_key> <data_bag> <id>

        value: 0<82>^D¾^B^A^@0^M^F     *<86>H<86>÷^M^A^A^A^E^@^D<82>^D¨0<82>^D¤^B^A^@^B<82>^A^A^@<87>ÊÕ        ~<89>µ^NÜç¦­Åªüyv§_m,+sÂ] +¿m^W.àË÷~^¥èÅ¾^^O3õ"ÃkN÷ÉÕ2< ^^H0^G/àª<81>/r¡úte½8 Õ^F^_´<80>ß»<94>î<91>-p$½%¡ãUY<94>B<8d>^\*4ê«<87><8f>Üñå<92>É^Hº  ò^LV<88><95>$<8a><8d><87>åù^Ee<8b>t95$pË±´·¨<97>-¨Z¶<87>¤y^CS.]æ<9f>¯Aí<88>¬÷ÓW=ì¤·^Q<82>^Og^Hþ<9b>Aöq<9f>EGØ÷XÑ<86><98>£n&<80>Ó^[<9c>Ì^Kj®è I ^?b¹cÇlA<81><9d>ÒÏó<86>ý ?F^_ñ¤(¼)IXë¸wò9.ÕÚ<99>²<99>xû =<9d>³þÃ<85><96>R7<9d>ä0ðu4n3 áòxoa<84>é^B^C^A^@^A^B<82>^A^@R,à÷9èCõ<96>¡i0ÇêM<97><83>Â<8d>ñ^WEÄkß^TÊä±3Ò^<9f><90>J<9d>$qÕ^XÔfÁÞ<9b>^Fÿ­n.j"XJ|TÛ^[¾Q<8b>]ZEXØ¤^OÝ<8e>£eÆªñ$ü@^\D²þx[^CKþÈ^@"<91>¢$<9a>â¿Û3ªyÙ^OZ
<96>5ý¿^?^G^Pfß:<99>ÎDk[ct¬^KÍ<82>çf<8a>:qô$í<9d>F^^Þ<9f>ÂN<86>ë<83>õê*F:nùkW<96>tS<88>:×[@²Å^\ÃSa^[t¾?^OÉ<86>²<99>Qá-è<8a>ýÚ9ô¨~}<81>BG<92>^?°^Y½é<95>×hÉcv^]é,^]|d^K y9µX V¸À®¿?¼¢¬¶<8c>ÖlVÀ{T^F!ÑÍ­ÓWë_iff<95>H×Ø3^H?^H<92>zéÁ^B<81><81>^@Õ7J^Y^^U_<8a>9¬£ÌÀ^[       FÇ^@ÑÚ®Å÷©C<9c>Ê^O§^Miü<94>äJ=VB³^AÌN9j­?ÕÁ?~[<8f>ngõÕÔWñ<91>ìòWq<91>"µT^_^Gv|^]göÄ0ËÑNPXû^KjjÛSüfM°e¨)ýÚ<86>µÃøîÌ¬æÇM<92>UlbBÆqyQV ôC:^M}xÃkÜu^B<81><81>^@£
\^V^?^ZÒ©áÿÊ^SgF£^GHO<92>^[ò¥O<8b>½ò^[EçæJq^^¨Á ¥M
^G7ë¡<8b>ÜÍ<90><90>¼ã^Cë:Zx, ú<9e>_P<91><89>¢º#^\c/rìÖÿÉ¹ÞØ&<90>osææPù{åQÐYã<83>^B^Xñ]þÓ'×ts­<81>^Nû<9d>ÀÙ<9c>A1WFz^Qm^[0e<84>?<91><93>Yk^H%^B<81><81>^@Éé^Wä}<93>?lx}<82><88>m^K­W71^Q<89>Ó¤i<8a>^C^[AF]^^X<96>6±<91><94>PQÍ<8e>ÐXë<8a><98>^R1lU¢e6<88>É.F<96>UÉÏôàñéü^U0>?<#ú^Y&ÐÊ­¢õÍ^AÍ¡      D5<9b>u(${<80>æû×÷^ZÚ^Y<8c>^H^K^^hP$Úã

        id:      tst
```

I would like to store the **value** in a file at /etc/app_key(this part shold be in the chef recipe)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `file` resource and its `content` property. Make sure you set the file owner and mode appropriately.

Comment: something like this. But how can I use the encrypted data bag? is it the same way?                                      
private_key = data_bag_item('impossible_things', private_key_name ['private_key']

file "some/directory/path/#{private_key_name}.pem" do
  content private_key
  owner 'root'
  group 'group'
  mode '0755'
end